# Misleading Estimated Marginal Means in Zero-inflated Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, lsmeans, marginal-effect

I am working with a number of zero-inflated poisson and nbinomial mixed models (with an offset), but when I produce estimated marginal means from them they are sometimes many orders of magnitude larger than without zero inflation (e.g. 3.0 vs. 0.0052), and are quite unexpectedly high given their actual biological meaning in the system I am studying. Should I be concerned, and if not how should I report these results in a way that draws attention to their estimation from zero inflated data (so that they do not look unnatural in terms of the sample size I'm presenting)?

Comment: Maybe. There are two issues here. 1. By default, the offsets are added to the estimates. But sometimes people want rates, and if so, add `offset =0` to the call. 2. Depending on the model class and how the emmeans support is provided, the EMMs may be only for the linear predictor component, rather than for the estimated mean with zero inflation included. So make sure you know what is being done.

Comment: Thanks Russ, setting the offset is a an excellent point that does not get made enough. I will keep investigating... I'm using glmmTMB with Emmeans.